# What does "get small for" mean?

Tags: meaning

> The set will **get small for** these #WildTalkers
>   (https://twitter.com/thezooonlatv/status/783105706689912832)

In the example above, what does "get small for" mean? Does it mean that the set will less spacious since these people are coming? Is this just another way of expression that these people will come to the set? I couldn't find any definition regarding this expression, so I think it's not an idiom.

Comment: Yes, there is no idiomatic meaning here for me. It’s an odd sentence without knowing the context, which is not immediately revealed by clicking your link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A meaning of *get* is equivalent to *become*.

> The set will get small for these = The set will *become* small for these

Sometimes *become*, or *get* when used like *become*, really means *be made*.

> The set will *be made* small for these.

Answer (score 0):

Even as a native speaker, it's a bit of a strange phrase to see. It doesn't read particularly well.

But in this instance I read it as:

> The set will **be small for** these #WildTalkers

or

> The set will **feel small for** these #WildTalkers

Imagine as more people enter the set, it becomes ("gets") relatively too small.

Comment: It could be all sorts of other things too. It could be referring to the fact that they will be talking about insects in the next episode  (looking at them on a small scale) rather than the larger mammals they usually investigate.

Comment: @OrbitalAussie I see your point r.e. "get small" but I'm not sure it implies that to me. Of course, it could be because it's a terrible sentence overall :)

Comment: Yes, a terrible sentence - with or without the missing context. I am not saying “will get small for” implies insects, just making the point that it implies so little that discussion is meaningless.